# How to perform long running Databse operation using RxJava2 till all the task executed and data inserted into Database in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-room, rx-android

I'm new in RxJava. I have currently executed three API calls parallel which is independent of each other via Retrofit using Single.Zip Operator. On getting a successful response of all three API calls, I have to insert the data from all three  APIs into Room database into Different entities which takes 20 seconds.

So I need to execute database operations inside Single.Zip operator. Because the logic is written inside `onSuccess` method running away before Database Operation performed.

I have tried to take separate Observer for performing database operation but didn't work.

```
public void callOfflineDataAPIs() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        Single<BaseResponse<ProductResponse>> single1 = getDataManager().getOfflineProductListApiCall(getDataManager().getLastTimeStampOfflineProductCall()).subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io()).observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui());
        Single<BaseResponse<LocationResponse>> single2 = getDataManager().getOfflineLocationListApiCall(getDataManager().getLastTimeStampOfflineLocationCall()).subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io()).observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui());
        Single<BaseResponse<OfflineMasterData>> single3 = getDataManager().getOfflineMasterDataListApiCall(getDataManager().getLastTimeStampOfflineMasterCall()).subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io()).observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui());

        DisposableSingleObserver<List<Boolean>> result = Single.zip(single3, single1, single2,
                (offlineMasterDataBaseResponse, productResponseBaseResponse, locationResponseBaseResponse) -> {
                    List<Boolean> apiCalls = new ArrayList<>();

                    apiCalls.add(masterDataCRUDOperation(offlineMasterDataBaseResponse));
                    apiCalls.add(productDataCRUDOperation(productResponseBaseResponse));
                    apiCalls.add(locationDataCRUDOperation(locationResponseBaseResponse));
                    return apiCalls;
                }).subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io()).observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui()).subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Boolean> apiCalls) {
                setIsLoading(false);
                LogHelper.e(TAG, "DisposableSingleObserver- onSuccess");
                boolean isSync = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < apiCalls.size(); i++) {
                    if (!apiCalls.get(i)) {
                        isSync = false;
                        LogHelper.e(TAG, "DisposableSingleObserver- onSuccess- apiCalls.get(i)", i);
                        callOfflineDataAPIs();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isSync) {
                    LogHelper.e(TAG, "IF-isSync");
                    if (BuildConfig.IS_CLIENT_BUILD) {
                        LogHelper.e(TAG, "IF-isSync-IS_CLIENT_BUILD-true");
                        getDataManager().setCurrentWarehouseKey(1);
                        getNavigator().onGoButtonClick();
                    } else {
                        LogHelper.e(TAG, "ELSE-isSync-IS_CLIENT_BUILD-false");
                        getWarehouseList();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                LogHelper.e(TAG, "DisposableSingleObserver- Throwable");
                setIsLoading(false);
                String errorMessage = new NetworkError(e).getAppErrorMessage();
                getNavigator().exitApplicationOnError(errorMessage);
            }
        });
}
```

Logic written inside onSuccess Method execute once all DB Operation performed.

Comment: Instead of performing the database operations in OnSubscribe, you could use a map or flatMap operator.

Comment: Hi Rishabh, can you please guide me how can I use it in my code?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/map-flatmap-switchmap-concatmap/

Comment: Ok. thank you. Will check. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi Rishabh, I have tried but don't know how can I use it in my code as I'm new in RxJava. Can you please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to something like:

```
        DisposableSingleObserver<List<Boolean>> result = Single.zip(single3, single1, single2,
                (offlineMasterDataBaseResponse, productResponseBaseResponse, locationResponseBaseResponse) -> {
                    List<Boolean> apiCalls = new ArrayList<>();

                    apiCalls.add(masterDataCRUDOperation(offlineMasterDataBaseResponse));
                    apiCalls.add(productDataCRUDOperation(productResponseBaseResponse));
                    apiCalls.add(locationDataCRUDOperation(locationResponseBaseResponse));
                    return apiCalls;
                }).subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                  .map(new Function<List<Boolean> apiCalls, List<Boolean> apiCalls>() {
                        @Override
                        public List<Boolean> apiCalls apply(List<Boolean> apiCalls) throws Exception {
                            // perform database operations here
                            return apiCalls;
                        }
                    })
                    .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<List<Boolean>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(User user) {
                           // Do something
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                             // Do something
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                             // Do something
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Hi Rishabh, I have tried but didn't worked. onComplete() method or onSuccess() method run away when DB Operation execution is going on.

Below three line execute long running DB Operations.
apiCalls.add(masterDataCRUDOperation(offlineMasterDataBaseResponse));
apiCalls.add(productDataCRUDOperation(productResponseBaseResponse));
apiCalls.add(locationDataCRUDOperation(locationResponseBaseResponse));

Comment: Hi RIshabh, I just want to hold onSuccess() method till all DB Operations completed.

onSuccess() Method need to be execute after the DB Operations Successfully performed.

Comment: Hey Malay, Do the DB operations happen on a different thread?

Comment: Hi Rishabh, I have tried the both way like perform operation on same thread/different thread but didn't worked.

Comment: But finally, I have sorted out the issue.